# Rails 4 Migration: has_and_belongs_to_many table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently try to switch a rails 3.2 app to rails 4.0. But I have one problem with a `has_and_belongs_many` model.

I have created a test app and I have the same problem there. This is what I have done:

Created two models: foo_clip and foo_url

```
class FooClip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :foo_urls

  attr_accessible :id, :name
end


class FooUrl < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :foo_clips

  attr_accessible :url
end
```

After this I have updated the migration files:

```
class CreateFooClips < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foo_clips do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateFooUrls < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foo_urls do |t|
      t.string :url
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now I have created the migration file for the has_and_belongs_to_many table

```
class CreateFooClipsFooUrls < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foo_clips_foo_urls do |t|
      t.belongs_to :foo_url
      t.belongs_to :foo_clip
    end
  end
end
```

As last step I created a seed file for testing:

```
foourl1 = FooUrl.create!(:url => 'http://www.google.com')
foourl2 = FooUrl.create!(:url => 'http://www.apple.com')

fooclip1 = FooClip.create!(:name => 'TestClip1')

fooclip1.foo_urls << foourl1
fooclip1.foo_urls << foourl2

fooclip1.save
```

Now I did:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

And got this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "foo_clips_urls" does not exist
LINE 5:         WHERE a.attrelid = '"foo_clips_urls"'::regcla...
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
               pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"foo_clips_urls"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

If I take a look at the postgres database the table is called: foo_clips_foo_urls

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Do you have any code on your `seed` file?

Comment: You see the whole content of the seed file above, there is no more code in it.

Comment: What do you mean by `I have updated migrations` - did you change any existing ones?

Comment: Yes I have added existing ones, this shouldn´t be a problem, if I drop, create, and migrate after that. Or?

Comment: It might be a problem if there are any migrations after those, as they might rely on given db state, you should never change existing migrations, unless you are 100% sure what's gona happen. So do you have any migrations after those you changed? Could you also paste your backtrace?

Comment: I have created this rails app from ground up, only to demonstrate the problem, there is nothing else in this rails 4 project.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding the join_table name to every model like:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :foo_urls,  :join_table => :foo_clips_foo_urls
```

Comment: For a more explicit example: http://ruby-journal.com/rails-4-changes-join-table-naming-convention/

Comment: additionally you can use `has_and_belongs_to_many :my_foo_urls, :class_name => 'Foo_Url',  :join_table => :foo_clips_foo_urls`