# has_and_belongs_to_many relations in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to add a relationship between BeautySalonEmployee and BeautySalonService models. There is the following migration:

```
class CreateBeautySalonEmployeesBeautySalonServices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :beauty_salon_employees_beauty_salon_services, id: false do |t|
        t.belongs_to :beauty_salon_employee
        t.belongs_to :beauty_salon_service
    end

    add_index :beauty_salon_employees_beauty_salon_services, [:beauty_salon_employee_id, :beauty_salon_service_id], unique: true, name: 'employee_service'
    add_index :beauty_salon_employees_beauty_salon_services, :beauty_salon_employee_id, name: 'employee'
    add_index :beauty_salon_employees_beauty_salon_services, :beauty_salon_service_id,  name: 'service'
  end
end
```

Models:

```
class BeautySalonEmployee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many           :beauty_salon_services
end

class BeautySalonService < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :beauty_salon_employees
end
```

And now when I'm trying to execute the following command:

```
BeautySalonEmployee.first.beauty_salon_services.build
```

I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'beauty_salon_employees_services'
```

What do I wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems Rails is being a bit overzealous in helping you out. It is condensing the table name into a more sensible format. Change the join table to `beauty_salon_employees_services`.

Comment: It's good, but can you give me example how to build a new relation using create! method?

Answer (score 1):

Give a   **`join_table`** option in your models like this

```
class BeautySalonEmployee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :beauty_salon_services,:join_table => :beauty_salon_employees_beauty_salon_services
end

class BeautySalonService < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :beauty_salon_employees,:join_table => :beauty_salon_employees_beauty_salon_services
end
```

Currently Rails is looking for a table **`beauty_salon_employees_services`** which does not exists.So you have to mention the join table like that.

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549133/rails-4-migration-has-and-belongs-to-many-table-name?rq=1)**